# Flickity.js before change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickity

Is there a way to execute code just before the slide is changed in Flickity.js? In my test case you can see, that it returns *location.hash* of changed slide. For example, I am swiping `#page1` slide to `#page2` slide, and location.hash returns `#page2`, but I want it to return *location.hash* of slide that being swiped, which in that case is `#page1`.

```js
var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity({
  imagesLoaded: true,
  content: true,
  cellAlign: 'left',
  pageDots: false,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  fullscreen: true,
  hash: true,
  lazyLoad: 2,
  zoom: true,
});

$carousel.on('change.flickity', function (){
  console.log(location.hash);
})
```

```css
.carousel-cell img{
  max-height: 90vh;
}


.carousel-cell {
  max-height: 90vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/2.2.1/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-hash@1.0.3/hash.js"></script>

<br>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell" id="page1" >
    <img class="carousel-cell-image"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell" id="page2" >
    <img class="carousel-cell-image"  src="https://helpx.adobe.com/content/dam/help/en/photoshop/using/convert-color-image-black-white/jcr_content/main-pars/before_and_after/image-before/Landscape-Color.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the documentation there's also the `select` event you can use, however updating your snippet with this seems to create other problems: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html#select

Comment: Yes, I saw that event, but this event works every time when slide is selected, even if the same slide is selected, this won't do

Comment: In that case there is nothing within the Flickity library to do what you require. I'd suggest finding an alternative.